# error after importing Swift into Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I try to use swift in OC,so I set **Defines Module YES** set **Product Module Name** with **Product Name**   and "import ProductName-Swift.h" in the .m file where i wanted to use swift

but the project cannot run ,cause a lot of mistakes in the "ProductName-Swift.h"
[image]

it seems something wrong with AppDelegate.swift,how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

here is how I solved the problem into the ProductName-Swift.h :
On this file, I can see the imports like that :

```
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
    @import UIKit;
    @import CoreGraphics;
    @import MessageUI;
    @import AddressBookUI;
    @import AddressBook;
    @import Foundation;
    @import ObjectiveC;
    @import MapKit;
    @import CoreLocation;
#endif
```

so, regarding the errors, I thought import doesn't work well.
First, compiler doesn't come in the if. It appears the

```
__has_feature(modules)
```

return false (whereas I set it on my build settings).

Ok, let go without and... error again. It appears the @import can only be used when modules is activated and he found no.... so I replaced all @import by #import and it works !!
But the last problem is the generation of the file each time I write in a swift file.. I have to change these import each... so I create this snippet code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
typedef ABRecordRef ABRecord;
```

(the last line is to replace ABRecord found in swift methods by ABRecordRef used in Objective-C)

Note : I don't have any #import for @import ObjectiveC but it seems it isn't needed.

PS : I'll create a post to ask help about the module set-but-not-for-compiler, if you think you have the answer.. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with MapKit framework, compiler pointed on missed declaration of MKMapViewDelegate in ProductName-Swift.h file. To solve this problem i added
 `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>` 
in bridge header file  PoductName-Bridging-Header.h.

You can try to add UIApplicationDelegate to this header. I hope this will help you.