# Issues with Swift generated header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2

I've got a project using Mapbox. The code base is mixed objC and Swift code. The class using Mapbox is written in Swift but is exposed to legacy objC code. I'm using !use_frameworks in my pod file to be able to use Swift pods as well. The problem I'm facing is that generated -swift.h file is wrong.

This is the problematic bit:

```
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC;
@import Mapbox;
@import CoreGraphics;
@import Foundation;
@import UIKit;
#endif
```

__has_feature(modules) is false so it won't import Mapbox module and the build fails later in the file

```
@interface MapBoxView : NSObject <MGLMapViewDelegate>
```

since it doesn't know the MGLMapViewDelegate.

I've got all the Define modules, Enable modules, etc. set to Yes in all project/target settings. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the classes marked with @objc where needed?

Comment: Yes: @objc public class MapBoxView : NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {...}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error after importing Swift into Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380340/error-after-importing-swift-into-objective-c)