# Swift & ObjC bridge - cannot find protocol declaration for "WKNavigationDelegate"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I saw there are many questions about Swift and Objective-C bridge including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380340/error-after-importing-swift-into-objective-c), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379636/issues-with-swift-generated-header-file), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c?noredirect=1&lq=1).... But none of them helped me so far.

When adding WKNavigationDelegate and WKScriptMessageHandler, compiler fails with message "Cannot find protocol declaration".

Project-Brigding-Header.h

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#include "xyz.h"
```

I have added `WebKit.framework` to `Link Binary With Libraries` under `target > Build Phases`. And made changes to build settings.

```
Defines Module : YES
Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries : YES
Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES
```

Do I have to do anything else to make it work?

Comment: try to import #import <UIKIT/UIKIT.h>

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Thanks but no luck :(

Comment: Then import you webkit in bridge header class

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>` in the bridging header?
Just add in a top of swift's file:

```
import WebKit
```

The bridging header only for application's inner classes which written with Objective-C.
[WebKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate) is a module (in swift's term).
**P.S.**
Also remove #import  from the bridging header.

Comment: Trying to use WKWebkit-related variables etc from Objective-C/C++ code. But obviously importing WebKit.h isn't the solution..

Comment: I've created example project and do not have problems with importing of WebKit. In Objective-C++ I use '#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>', in Swift file I use 'import WebKit'. All works fine. Can you add code of your imports and code where you are trying to initiate WKWebView?

Comment: Perhaps there is circular reference or something. It's an old old project someone else wrote in ObjC and using C library. After looking at it since posting question, I think calling webview method through variable stored in AppDelegate is not a great idea, and that's where compiler can't find the protocol for WKWebView.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I'll refactor so that I don't need to call webview method.